# How to fix the "ConnectionResetError" when traning BERTopic?

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I now have the abstract texts of many papers and I want to extract the topics through the BERTopic model. I have completed the pre-processing of the text.

I am training a `Bertopic` model and this error occurred: `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host",...`

How can I fix it?

```
text = pd.read_excel("data1.xlsx")
text["Year"] = text["Year"].astype("int64")
abstract = text["abstract"]
year = text["Year"]

stopLists = list(pd.read_csv("stopWords.txt",names = ['w'], sep = '/n').w)
wordLists = jieba.lcut(" ".join(abstract))
words = [word for word in wordLists if word not in stopLists and len(word)>1]

umap = UMAP(n_neighbors = 15,n_components = 5,min_dist = 0.0, metric = 'cosine',random_state = 100)
topicModel = BERTopic(umap_model=umap, calculate_probabilities = True, nr_topics="auto")
topics,probs = topicModel.fit_transform(words)
```

Comment: How is `Bertopic` and `requests` related? Could you include some code?

Comment: Sry,I'm just wondering if the request interval is not set in the BERTopic source code and therefore causing this. I don't have the code related to ```requests``` in my actual work.

Comment: Again, could you include your actual work? I couldn't find anyone with the same problem, so I think it's related to your code.

Comment: All the information I have is here.

Comment: Much better! I saw that by default `BERTopic` uses `all-MiniLM-L6-v2` as an embedding model. Could you try training with; `topic_model = BERTopic(embedding_model="paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2", verbose=True)` and share results? It downloads the model through `huggingface`, so if the issue persists we could download the model manually so that it can be accesed from the cache.

Comment: Still the same problem. It seems to have gone wrong before even starting to build the model. The error points to ```d:\Anaconda\file\envs\BERTopic_Env\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:790```. I checked the source code and found that the wrong line was about making requests, so I think the problem may be caused by my network condition.

Answer (score -1):

I think following points will help:

1. Check your network connection to ensure it is stable and not experiencing any disruptions.
2. Retry the operation, as the connection issue might be temporary.
3. Increase the timeout for requests made by `BERTopic` by setting a higher timeout value. If `BERTopic` is using the requests library, you can set the `timeout` parameter when making requests.
4. Try downloading the model manually and providing the local path to the model when initializing the BERTopic model.

You can try running the updated code to download

```
text = pd.read_excel("data1.xlsx")
text["Year"] = text["Year"].astype("int64")
abstract = text["abstract"]
year = text["Year"]

stopLists = list(pd.read_csv("stopWords.txt", names=['w'], sep='/n').w)

wordLists = jieba.lcut(" ".join(abstract))
words = [word for word in wordLists if word not in stopLists and len(word) > 1]

umap = UMAP(n_neighbors=15, n_components=5, min_dist=0.0, metric='cosine', random_state=100)

topicModel = BERTopic(embedding_model="paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2", calculate_probabilities=True, nr_topics="auto", verbose=True)

topics, probs = topicModel.fit_transform(words)
```

By explicitly mentioning `embedding_model` parameter, it let's us download `paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2` model manually.

Comment: thx a lot. I have downloaded the model manually from ```hugging face```, but I don't know how to use it. I tried the ```pipeline()```, ```AutoModel.from_pretrained()``` in ```transformers``` package. None of them run successfully, from the initiation results of BERTopic. Could you give me some examples for using the downloaded models?

Comment: For BERTopic library you can try executing the following code: ` ## Installing bertopic #pip install bertopic 

from bertopic import BERTopic 

topic_model = BERTopic() 

model_path = "pathtoyour/model" 

topic_model.load(model_path) 

topics, probabilities = topic_model.fit_transform(words) ` 

Try access models from server only, as it isn't feasaible to download models everytime. 

If you are trying to access models from HuggingFaceHub via API. Make sure to create an access token for your API. 

Hope this helps